# How to get only the class name with no package information using java refleciton

Tags: java, reflection

`Class MyClass` has a method `getMyClassId` and I want to invoke something like this :

```
Method method = clazz.getMethod("get" + clazz.getName() + "Id");     
method.invoke(myObject)
```

But clazz.getName() returns the fully qualified package information, I could do some string manipulation, but wondered if there was a better way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [class.getSimpleName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Method method = clazz.getMethod("get" + clazz.getSimpleName() + "Id");
```